# Magento: Get the parent category of the current store/website

Tags: magento, categories, product

I'm using [this code](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/176389/P15/#t369242) to display the parent categories of a product in the breadcrumbs.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with multi store setups where a product is additionally assigned to a category which doesn't exist in the current store. Example:
On [this product page](http://www.geschenkhexe.ch/kugelschreiber-kamera.html) the breadcrumb links to the category "Minikameras" which actually is a category of another website/store.

What's the best way to display only categories of the active website/store?

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to get the root category of current store.

```
<?php Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?
       Mage::app('store', 'website');//enter your store and website here
       $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
       $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
       foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): 
       $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id);
       $cat_name = $_category->getName();
       $cat_url =  $_category->getUrl();
       endforeach;
       ?>
```

This is another approach. It will list the category names and the category urls. all you have to do is to enter the store and website. Hope it helps.